# Get string equivalent of recordId in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

@api recordId - yields a property of the type ID

I want that to be turned into a string (ie. strId) before the next lines run, in order to use it to build an endpoint URL for an http call (ie. GetJson)

```
endpointURL = 'https://blahblah?AccountId=' + this.strId;
@wire(GetJson, {strEndPointURL:'$endpointURL'})
    retval ({error,data}){
        if (data) {
            this.resultjson = data.SiteDataAccount;
            console.log('GetJson endpointURL ==> : ', this.endpointURL); 
            console.log('GetJson strId ==> : ', this.strId) ; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@api recordId
```

This is string in javascript. Javascript is [loosely typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) language and so you need not worry about it.

[image]